# Metric space in Topology class

Tags: general-topology

On the set of integers $\mathbb Z$, show that the function d, defined as follow, is a metric : $$ d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x=y \\
 \min\{1/n! \mid n! \text{ divides } |x-y|\} & \text{if } x\neq y \end{cases}$$

metric space axiom.

- $d(x,y) \geq 0 \quad \forall(x,y) \in X\times X$
- $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$
- $d(x,y)=d(y,x) \forall x,y \in X$
- $d(x,y)+d(y,z) \geq d(x,z) \quad \forall x,y,z\in X$

I have a difficulty proving 4th axiom. I don't know how to start. Is there someone to help?

Comment: There are some minor errors in your statements of the metric space axioms.

Comment: As to the problem: I think it's helpful to notice that if $n!$ divides $|x - y|$ then $m!$ does as well as long as $m<n$.

Comment: More specifically, the direction of the first inequality is wrong, and in the second axiom, it surely should read $d(x,y)$, because otherwise a metric space could only contain a single element.

Comment: I had a typing error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $a$ divides $b-c$ iff it divides $c-b$, so that the absolute value sign in the condition $n!$ divides $|x-y|$ may be dropped and the condition can be written as $n!|x-y$ (where this single $|$ is the symbol for "divides").

Now for each pair of distinct integers $x,y$ let $n_{xy}$ denote the largest $n$ such that $n!|x-y.$ Then $d(x,y)=1/n_{xy}!.$ Since $d$ is nonnegative and $d(x,x)=0$ the triangle inequality is clear if any two of $x,y,z$ are equal, so we assume they are distinct.

To look at $d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ we note that if $w=\min(n_{xy},n_{yz})$ then $w!$ divides $x-z=(x-y)+(y-z).$ It may happen that a larger factorial than $w!$ divides $x-z$, but we do have $w \le n_{xz}$ in any case. So we have
$$d(x,z)=1/n_{xz}! \le 1/w! \le 1/n_{xy}!+1/n_{yz}!=d(x,y)+d(y,z).$$
 (In the second inequality, since $w$ is the smaller of the two of $n_{xy},n_{y,z}$ its reciprocal factorial is the reciprocal factorial of one of them, so is less than their sum.) This actually shows the slightly stronger inequality $d(x,z) \le \min [d(x,y),d(y,z)],$ reminiscent of a $p$ adic norm.